# Share same information on multiple web pages

Tags: asp.net

How can I share the same ordered list across multiple web pages without writing code behind? In this manner the information would only have to be updated in one location.

Comment: via viewstate - (with out write code behind (?!) - means you won to read it and write it in javascript only ?)

Comment: @tszoro Why are you trying to avoid codebehind?

Comment: @Beska You mean different pages ? or different sites ? ok the next possible is the Application Variables.

Comment: @Beska I actually do most things in code behind, just seeing if there may be some simple html ways of doing this that I don't know of. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build an ASP.NET user control (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) so you can put your list there and use your user control on every page you need.

With this, you'll have to alter your ordered list only in the user control, and this update will be available everywhere you've used the user control.